# java script not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I am working on a website in which I want to close the browser window/tab when the Logout Successful page loads. I am doing this because after the Logout workflow if 'back' button is pressed on browser, it displays the previous page with all the confidential info visible. Since I cleared the session in the corresponding servlet, user cannot do anything after the logout but display of data is of quite concern.

For this pupose I am using below code (Logout.jsp)-

```
<body onload="self.close();">
 <center>
    You have been successfully logged out.<br>
 </center>
</body>
```

The problem is that the above code is working fine on IE however, it is not working on Firefox and Chrome. I checked all the settings related to Java Script for Chrome and they are exactly the same as of my browser.

Alternatively, I tried to clear the history. For this purpose I used below code which I found on some website -

```
<body onload="window.history.forward(0)">
 <center>
    You have been successfully logged out.<br>
    Kindly close the browser for security reasons.<br>
 </center>
</body>
```

But this code is not working in any of the browser.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

---------------- UPDATE ---------------

For the second option (i.e. clearing history), after much google and work, I was able to make it work. The solution is as below -

If a user follows the navigation page1 -> page2. And you want to stop user from page2 to go back to page1 then add below code on page1 -

```
<body onload="window.history.forward();">
   //rest of the body
</body>
```

I tested it in IE and found it working perfectly.

Now, I am left with the original issue that why script is not working in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do that. Just verify if the session exists. If it doesn't ( since it logged off ) you send him automatically to login page. That way your site is hack proof because i can eliminate from firebug or any console the line where you just close my tab, and therefor i can still see the data.

Comment: I am checking the existence of session at the begining of each servlet. If session does not exist then the Error Page will be displayed. Now, when I press the back button it displays the data (previous one) but when I refresh the page then it goes to the Error Page.

Comment: than secure the date of logout in a session and if it is set and smaller than the current date send him to the Error Page. Do this for all pages except login page and if he logs in you delete the session of logout date if any. Other solution is keeping a cookie. Or at log out send him to a page with a redirection. That way each time he hits the back button he will be automatically be sent forth, so never reaching the logged state from which he logged out.

Comment: The issue of data visibility is solved (atleast for IE). Please see my update above. Now my only concern is why the same java script is not working in Chrome and FireFox when it is perfectly working in IE. Is there any setting needs to be done which I am missing out?

Comment: why don't you use onload="window.location = myloginpage.php" ? it is cross-browser and you put this in page one of the following chain: logout -> pg1 ->login. from login you can't back to pg1.